# Actionscript 3.0 - how to get rid of unloaded 'swf file' directly?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory

Question :=(.

I'm making application for android. (Main frame made air and load swf files)

It's almost finished other than "memory optimization".

So, i'm wondering is this. ------->

I need to remove directly when swf file unloaded. and i know it's hard.

but, some swf files has 30 ~ 50 mb. (this is flash animation).

memory duplication made problem in android...

so, my question is how can i delete directly swf file memory.

please. let me know. i need to sleep :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'delete directly swf file memory'. You need to remove all references to anything that you've used in that swf - that's the only way. The file itself doesn't stand as a whole in the memory. Instead - each object you've used from it goes into memory, and needs to be cleared by garbage collector once it's completely not used (not displayed, no references to it).

Comment: thanks. :) And how about this... limit VM memory size. if i can change the memory size, it's no problem. can i change the memory size?

Comment: You you can't. Don't look for such kind of solutions, as the real and best solution is obvious - limit the size and complexity of  your files :)